# check header inclusion for c++ standard libraries

Tags: c++11, clang++

I need to know in a library, if a specific header file is included or not.

like

```
//a.cpp
#include <array>
#include "incl.hpp"

//incl.hpp
//check if array is included or not
```

I can do by checking _GLIBCXX_ARRAY  and *ARRAY* macro for g++ and msvc. Can you please tell me how to do the equivalent in clang ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I need to do expose some functions specific to a header file. Those functions are templated functions and it will unnecessarily increase build time.